# A simplicial complex with vanishing first homology but nonzero fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm interested in the simplicial complex and I do not know much of algebraic topology to use the answers that question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110158/what-if-i-want-to-look-for-a-space-with-vanishing-first-homology-but-nonzero-fun#

Thanks!!

Comment: The Poincare homology sphere is a common example. The wikipedia article will tell you how to construct it, and you can make it into a simplicial complex.

Comment: you can think it in this way... 1st every finitely presented group can be thought of as a fundamental group of a 4-manifold, 2nd every manifold has a simplicial structure, and 3 rd is $H_1(X) = [pi_1(X), pi_1(X)]$ i.e abelianization of fundamental group...so try to find a group whose abelianization is trivial...then you are doone with existence... and if you want a proper ans then @MikeMiller has already suggested a good one

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but if you don't know enough algebraic topology to understand the answers to the MO question linked, then you need to learn more algebraic topology to get a comprehensible answer to your question... You're not going to find simpler examples. As you can see the first answers you got here as the same that as the ones that are on MO (Poincaré homology sphere, 2-dimensional classifying space of a perfect group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [alternating group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) $A_5$ which is [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group). Take a wedge sum of 60 oriented circles indexed by elements of $A_n$ and to each relation in $A_5$---for example, $(1,2,3)(1,3,2)=\mathrm{id}$---glue a $2$-cell in such a way that its boundary will correspond to the relation, in this case, to the circle $(1,2,3)(1,3,2)$. This will trivialize the loop $(1,2,3)(1,3,2)$. In this way, you obtain a $2$-complex with fundamental group $A_5$ and the first homology group, being its abelianization, will be zero.